# How can I save states of my inputs in android?

Tags: android

I am having problem for saving states of my input till now I just save edittext value only. When savebtn click all the states should be save I want to save the value of my input after closing my app when I am opening it, it should give me same output?

Main Activity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    CheckBox CheckBox1;
    private Button btn1;
    private Button btn2;
    private SharedPreferences savednotes;
    private EditText editText1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.Cnclbtn);
        btn2= (Button)findViewById(R.id.Savebtn);
        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        savednotes = getSharedPreferences("notes",MODE_PRIVATE);
       editText1.setText(savednotes.getString("tag","Default"));
       CheckBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);


       //


        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btn2.setOnClickListener(saveButtonListener); 
    }
    private void makeTag(String tag){
        String or = savednotes.getString(tag, null);
         SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = savednotes.edit();
         preferencesEditor.putString("tag",tag); //change this line to this
         preferencesEditor.commit();
     }

    public OnClickListener saveButtonListener = new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            makeTag(editText1.getText().toString());    

            ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText1.getWindowToken(),0);
        }};

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Profiles"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="User Name" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="App Sound"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Ring on cell" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Ring on msg" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Vibrate" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:entries="@array/dropdown"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Savebtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:text="Save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Cnclbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Savebtn"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Savebtn"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:text="Cancel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why can't you do it the way you are now, with `SharedPreferences`? There is no automagical way to save everything. You have to decide what type of persistent storage you want to use and save the data you need.

Comment: i tried that bro but i am unable to save states with shared prefrences only edittext working n others like spinner,seekbar and checkbox they arenot working. some having problem with onclicklistener they arenot supporting the button to save the states?

Comment: You are going to need to be a little more specific on what you mean by "save states". What exactly do you want to save?

Comment: If, for example orb, you want to save if the button is checked, you will need to save a boolean in SharedPrefs, db, or another file. Then check it and set the button accordingly

Comment: bro i just want to save the input i m giving so when i reopen my activity my input didnot lost like username gul when i open it should be present there? and that thing is happening in editbox but not in others

Comment: bro, I only see one place where you are trying to save anything to SharedPrefs

Comment: you don't need to do anything on click at checkbox or seekbar, just on save click, take the `value`,  `selectedItemPosition` or `isChecked` for your views and store them in `SharedPreferences`

Comment: Check this Link - http://androhub.com/android-sharedpreferences/

Comment: @codemagic yes bro because i tried rest but didnt work

Comment: Ok, bro, if something isn't working then you need to show the code which isn't working and explain the desired and current results including error messages etc...

Comment: at yazan how to do that i dont get it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

assume you have a EditText, Spinner and a CheckBox:

```
EditText txtName;
CheckBox chkAgree;
Spinner spnLevel;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    txtName = ...;
    chkAgree = ...;
    spnLevel = ...;

    btnSave.setOnClick(
    ...
    save();
    });

    load();
}

private void save(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("my_app_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("name_value",txtName.getText().toString());
        editor.putInt("selected_level",spnLevel.getSelectedItemPosition());
        editor.putBoolean("is_agree",chkAgree.isChecked());
        editor.commit();
}//save()

private void load(){
         SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("my_app_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         txtName.setText(sharedPref.getString("name_value",""));
         spnLevel.setSelection(sharedPref.getInt("selected_level",0));
         chkAgree.setChecked(sharedPref.getBoolean("is_agree",false));
}//save()
```

**Not compiled**, but should be correct.
complete `onCreate()` based on your current class

Comment: this was the best way i could ever seek the sharedprefrence thing :) u r such a genious :)